# Visual Studio - Shortcut for Reload Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

Is there a VS shortcut which reloads the current solution and reopens all open files?

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this Web site; I think it will lead you to what you are looking for.

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/01/27/reloading-all-projects-with-vscommands/

Comment: I'm using VSCommands, however, reloading all projects is not the same as reloading the solution.